# html text not format right with page width

Tags: html

I made a most simple example of my problem. First paragraph with "Loren Ipsum" formats well when resizing the browser. But second real text not formats right. like:[image]

What is the problem?

JSfiddle example:
https://jsfiddle.net/tling/dqjzezh8/

My HTML source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
</head>

<body>
<div style=" border: 1px black solid">

    <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris 
    nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor 

    </p>

    <p>
    Cillum to care appears problemac 
    in the exercitation mollit, as evidenced by higher rates of preventable incididuntinc
    and consequatat consequatbc visits, as well as a lower percentage 
of adults who reported having a usual source of aute, compared to laborum.
    </p>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What you have displays fine. Do you have CSS or anything that might be affecting the page? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xgqMGJ Please give us a working demo that reproduces the problem.

Comment: no extra css, all codes are in the question.

Comment: Are you seeing the same issue in the codepen link I provided?

Comment: Maybe you have some encoded characters or something in your actual HTML? I see a weird line break after `problemac` in the code you pasted. Doesn't do anything to the HTML in my example though.

Comment: The line break is done by myself to see all the text in my text editor..

Comment: Are you seeing the same issue in the codepen link I provided?

Comment: no, only from my local chrome/firefox/ie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your issue in JSFiddle (in Chrome), as you provided. By changing the newline character placement, I changed the wrapping of the text inside the box.

What is so strange is that the newline characters in JSFiddle do not in any way correspond with where the new lines begin in the HTML output.

Take away the box and the html headers in JSFiddle and leave just the paragraph tags, and the same issue occurs.

Copy-pasting your code into a new html file on my desktop and running it in Chrome, I do not see the issue.

Therefore, the issue is not your HTML code. There MUST be some implicit CSS on your page. JSFiddle does load its own CSS and JS on the page, so that may be why you are able to reproduce it there.

My best possible explanation, by process of eliminating all other possibilities I can think of - is CSS you are not aware is being injected into your page. Try opening up the Developer Tools in Chrome or Firefox and checking the network and page resources that get loaded. View the source, too. Do you see any external CSS files?

One other possiblity - file encoding. Are you using UTF-8? If not, you should be. That might explain some erratic behavior.

Comment: I finally figured it out: since the text is copied and pasted from pdf. The white space is actually '0xa0' instead of ' ', which prevents the html from formatting right. So you are right, very "implicit CSS".

Comment: @TianyunLing Right, I mean the other implicit CSS =p. Yes, character encoding is my arch nemesis. I would recommend using Notepad++ and showing all characters. That will eliminate this problem for you in the future. Glad I was able to help.